# zsh: killed how to avoid the killed error in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a fuzzy match script in Python. As the code is running I get this output. I am not sure how the command is being killed.

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import recordlinkage

al_usa = pd.read_csv('al_all_reference_usa.dta.csv', index_col='id')
al_sample = pd.read_csv('al_final.dta.csv', index_col='company_number', low_memory=False)

indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.full()

candidates = indexer.index(al_usa, al_sample)
print(len(candidates))

compare = recordlinkage.Compare()
compare.string('companyname', 
               'name', 
               threshold=0.90, 
               label='business')
compare.string('state',
               'state', 
               threshold=0.90, 
               label='state')
features = compare.compute(candidates, al_usa,
                        al_sample)
```

Here is the error:

```
zsh: killed     /Users/anaconda3/bin/python
```

How can I fix this so the code can work?

Comment: I'm guessing the program is being killed because it ran out of memory. You can try to run the program again and watch the memory consumption.

Comment: Check your process limits with `ulimit -Sa`. The process is likely being killed, because one of those limits is violiated. Could be "max memory size" but also others.

Comment: How big are `al_all_reference_usa.dta.csv` and `al_final.dta.csv`?

Comment: "Buy more RAM" -- not exactly a software-development issue.